# Query posts published after a certain date in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to write a `WP_Query` where I'm calling only posts that have been posted after march 2012. I can successfully call posts that are just in March 2012, but struggling to do 'from March 2012 onwards'.

```
    $current_year = date('2012');
    $current_month = date('>3'); // This doesn't work
    $current_month = date('3'); // This DOES work

    $custom_query = new WP_Query("year=$current_year&monthnum=$current_month&order=ASC&posts_per_page=-1");
```

Am I missing something simple, or does this have to get more complicated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "Time Parameters" section in http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query has a note about date ranges.  Using the same technique:

```
$query_string = "order=ASC&posts_per_page=-1";

// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '2012-03-01'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

Answer (score 17):

Since WordPress version 3.7, there's the WP_Query argument [`date_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) that works perfectly for this type of query.

[As you can see in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters), you can specify a date query with the `after` argument. The `after` can either be a strtotime()-compatible string, or an array of 'year', 'month', 'day' values.

For your example, something like the following should work:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'date_query'     => array(
        'after' => array(
            'year'  => 2012,
            'month' => 3,
            'day'   => 1,
        ),
    ),
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Or with a strtotime()-string:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'date_query'     => array( 'after' => '2012-03-01' ),
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: you can also include the after date into the query by adding `'inclusive' => true` otherwise only the posts from the 2nd will be included

Comment: Use the _after_ `date_query` like alisspers says with `strtotime()` function like so: `strtotime('-3 day')` or `strtotime('-2 week')` or `strtotime('next Thursday')` Read about more options in PHP's docs: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php