# Hide old event posts older than current date

Tags: wordpress, while-loop

My current loop shows 5 upcoming events, however when the day of the event passes i cannot get those event posts to not be displayed. here is my code...

```
<?

wp_reset_query();
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'events',
                  'showposts' => 5,
                  'meta_key'=>'event_date',  
                  'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
                  'order' => ASC));

while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

?>

<li>
<?php $eventDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('event_date')); ?>
<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
<span class="date"><strong>Event Date:</strong> <? echo $eventDate->format('d/m/Y'); ?></span>
</li>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

...any help would be most appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [WordPress Query posts published after a certain date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778122/wordpress-query-posts-published-after-a-certain-date)

Comment: no, this is different. these are event posts which have an custom field called event_date. its when the event date passes that i want the post not to be included in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

As your post has custom field you can do something like this:

```
<?php

 // Get the current date
 $current_date = date('M d, Y');
 $current_date = strtotime( $current_date );


 query_posts(array('post_type' => 'events',
              'showposts' => 5,
              'meta_key'=>'event_date',  
              'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
              'order' => ASC));

 while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

   // Get the custom field
   $post_date = get('date');
   $post_date = strtotime( $post_date );


   // If older than current date, don't show it
   if( $post_date > $current_date ):

?>

  <li>
   <?php $eventDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('event_date')); ?>
   <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
   <span class="date"><strong>Event Date:</strong> <? echo $eventDate->format('d/m/Y'); ?></span>
  </li>


<?php
     endif;
 endwhile;
?>
```

Hope this helps.